# Implementing push notifications with UrbanAirship and Google App Engine

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm implementing push notifications in an app. I think i have to two choices and I can't decide which is better.

I have my own server where the push notifications originate, it thens uses the Urban Airship API to send the push notifications.

However when a user registers for push notification on device and it returns the device token. But how do I do go about getting the token both to Urban Airship and my server?

Should I upload the token from the device to Urban Airship, and then upload again from the device to my server?

Or should I upload from the device to my server, and then upload the token from my server to urban airship?

Are there any open source apps that have a similar situation? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

(the reason I'm using Urban Airship is because my server is on Google App engine, which doesn't have the functionality to communicate with APNS directly, so I'm having to store the device token (with a userID that the app provides) in GAE app, and it will also be stored by Urban airship)

Comment: What does the Urban Airship documentation suggest?

Comment: As far as I can see, it only deals with it's API and client library? Not implementation on the app's side.

Comment: Urban Airship deals with the Apple server and deregisters tokens when users turn off push notification. Can't you just get the information from UA and sync with your server? (https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/APIs:+Push+iOS)

Comment: I need to associate a user ID with the device token. The User ID is used to fetch content and if theres an update push it to the device, using it's token.